# How can I deal with multi-character operators when lexing with shlex in Python?

Tags: python, token, lexer, shlex

I'm writing a language parser/interpreter, and I figured I could use the shlex module for generating tokens, but ran into an issue when working with multi-character operators, such as `+=` or `**`.  The shlex module will lex those as two separate operators, which is not ideal.

```
>>> t = shlex.shlex('x += 3')
>>> t.get_token()
'x'
>>> t.get_token()
'+'
>>> t.get_token()
'='
```

I thought I'd try adding operator characters to shlex.wordchars, but that creates problems with code without white space:

```
>>> t = shlex.shlex('x+=3')
>>> t.wordchars += '+=*-/'
>>> t.get_token()
'x+=3'
```

So then I had the idea that I could just manually rebuild operators from tokens when I have multiple tokens in a row that could be a valid operator.  For example, if I have a `+` token followed by a `=`, then I would concatenate them to make a '+='.  However, this solution creates a problem with expressions like `x - -3`.  It would get tokenized into `x`, `--`, and `3`, which also isn't what I want.

Is there any way to do what I want simply with the shlex module?  Or am I probably going to have to write a tokenizer myself?